# Why Bootstrap navbar with angular behaving a bit different?

Tags: angular, angular-ui-bootstrap

I'm trying to use bootstrap navbar with Angular 4. Below is the code snippet for sample Menu I need.

```
<nav class="navbar navbar-inverse">
  <div class="container-fluid">
    <div class="navbar-header">
      <a class="navbar-brand" href="#">WebSiteName</a>
    </div>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav">
      <li class="active"><a href="#">Home</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 1</a></li>
      <li><a href="#">Page 2</a></li>
    </ul>
    <ul class="nav navbar-nav navbar-right">
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-user"></span> Sign Up</a></li>
      <li><a href="#"><span class="glyphicon glyphicon-log-in"></span> Login</a></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</nav>
```

If I put this code in simple html file and open in web browser, I see the Menu correctly as below:[image]

However, if I try to use same code in navbar component that I created in angular 4 and bind that in index.html, I see output as below:

[image]

Am I missing anything here?

Here is my index.html:

```
<!doctype html>
<html>
<head>
  <meta charset="utf-8">
  <title>MyWebsite</title>
  <base href="/">

  <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
  <link rel="icon" type="image/x-icon" href="favicon.ico">
  <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
  <script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.2.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
  <script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>

</head>
<body style="background: #e0e0eb">
  <app-root>Loading...</app-root>
</body>
</html>
```

Also, in app.component.html

```
<app-navbar></app-navbar>
```

Comment: show us your index.html code

Comment: HI Dinesh, I've edited the description to have index.html

Comment: can you inspect navbar and check css styles are applied or not. and check for console for js errors. it would be helpful to debug if you give jsfiddle or codepen.io snippet

Comment: Don't post code as images. It makes it very hard to read, and impossible to copy, paste, amend, and index. Post code as text.

Comment: @Dinesh I'll try that out today, and get back to you.
@JB Nizet Sorry for that, I agree. I tried posting my code as `code` and `html` but the it displayed the evaluated text in there.

Comment: If you want an easy and clean integration of bootstrap components (like dropdowns) inside an Angular application, you should switch to bootstrap 4, forget about jquery and the JS of bootstrap, and use ng-bootstrap instead. https://ng-bootstrap.github.io/#/home.